# My tabs are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I don't know why are my tabs not working 
I've been working with it for hours now !!
https://jsfiddle.net/mshgwjrb/

```
$('.tabs').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $active = $this.find('li .active');
    var $link = $active.find('a');
    var $activeTab = $($link.attr('href'));

    $this.on('click', '.tab-', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currLink = $(this);
        var id = this.hash;

        if (!currLink.is('.active')) {
            $activeTab.removeClass('active');
            $active.removeClass('active');

            $(id).addClass('active');
            currLink.parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There's a typo on `li .active`, you wanted `li.active` to target any LI with an `.active` class

Comment: what do you suggest ?

Comment: S/he suggest that you fix your typo from `li .active` to `li.active`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/mshgwjrb/1/

Comment: It's not `this.hash`, but `$(this).attr('href')`

Comment: Your id's are wrong in your html.  They are all `tab_01`.  They need to be updated accordingly; 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: I fixed the ids but when I click on a tab the content does not disappear

Comment: I'd simplify it, a lot -> **https://jsfiddle.net/mshgwjrb/6/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. Compare the code that you have and the one I gave you here. You will understand the problem.

```
$('.tabs').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $active = $this.find('li .active');
    var $link = $active.find('a');
    var $activeTab = $($link.attr('href'));



    $this.on('click', '.tab-', function(e){
    alert("asdf")
        //e.preventDefault();
        var currLink = $(this);
        var id = this.hash;
         $active = $("#tabsContent").find('.active');
         $activeTab.removeClass('active');
            $active.removeClass('active');

            $(id).addClass('active');

    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

In [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/mshgwjrb/1) you have an error in your html where all of your tab IDs used the same ID. Also your method for running your JQuery wasn't the cleanest. I have rewritten your example for you [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/jpeak/oxoc00xg/). The new JQuery code looks like this:

```
$('ul.tabs').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
   var id = $(this).children("a").attr('href');
   $('.tab.active').removeClass('active');
   $(id).addClass('active');
});
```